# Correct way to call a member function via a QHash with member function pointers

Tags: c++, qt, function-pointers, qhash

I have a Server class that processes `QJsonObject` data and handles it according to a key set in the data.

At the moment, I use a big if-then-else statement to decide what to do like this:

```
const QString action = jsonObject.value(KEY_ACTION).toString();
if (action == SOME_ACTION) {
    // do something
} else if (action == SOME_OTHER_ACTION) {
    // do something else
}
```

and so on. Now, meanwhile, I have quite a lot of actions, and for each one, my server has to check all cases until it finds the correct one. I thus wondered if there was a nicer way to do this.

I thought about having the data processing in different functions and having a `QHash` with the respective function pointer to the respective function for each action like this:

In the constructor:

```
const QHash<QString, void(Server::*)(const QJsonObject &)> processFunctionsMap {
    { SOME_ACTION, &Server::processSomeAction },
    { SOME_OTHER_ACTION, &Server::processSomeOtherAction }
}
```

And the respective functions:

```
void Server::processSomeAction(const QJsonObject &data)
{
    ...
}
```

and then to invoke the matching function:

```
if (! processFunctionsMap.contains(action)) {
    // Catch this case
}
(this->*processFunctionsMap.value(action))(jsonObject);
```

This seems to work, but I'm not a C++ pro, so my question is if this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is reasonable, but you've changed the no-matches scenario from executing an `else` block (potentially doing nothing at all) to instant undefined behavior.

You need to separate the hash lookup from the call so you can insert a check for successful lookup in between.  With C++ standard collections (`std::map` which is a red-black tree, `std::unordered_map` which is a hashtable), that'd be a call to `find(key)` which returns an iterator... you compare it to `map.end()` and make very sure not to dereference if they are equal.  `QHash`, or any other non-standard hashtable, will surely provide something similar.

- [Understanding what QHash does when key not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39973392/103167)

Comment: Thanks for confirming doing so is okay :-) Sorry for the incomplete example, I'll edit my code to avoid undefined behavior.